# ANDROID STUDIO / SQLiteLog: (1) near "LIMIT": syntax error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete the duplicates that I am getting in my database using DELETE function of my SQL with LIMIT 1 but it is showing me the "LIMIT" syntax error .

```
        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR , age INT(3))");

        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Vaishant', 21)");

        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Tommy',4)");

        myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = 'Vaishant' LIMIT 1");
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not support `LIMIT` in a `DELETE` statement.
Use a subquery that returns the [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) of a row that contains the name that you search for:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid FROM users WHERE name = 'Vaishant' LIMIT 1)";
myDatabase.execSQL(sql);
```

If you want to delete the duplicate names and keep only 1, then you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.name = users.name AND u.rowid < users.rowid)
```

or:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM users GROUP BY name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your delete statement you are using limit with Delete query. You should use it as below:

1. First add id column as primary key in your table

   ```
   myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR , age INT(3))");
   ```
2. change the query of delete as below

   ```
   myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM users 
   WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT id FROM 
   (SELECT id, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) AS row_num FROM users )t 
   WHERE row_num > 1)");
   ```